# Is it possible to map a subdomain to a domain?

Tags: domain, subdomain, mapping

Does anyone have experience with this?

Is it possible to map a subdomain to a domain?

Can I make "example.subdomain.maindomain.com" point to an external website exampledomain.com's content  (but still keep the example.subdomain.maindomain.com URL in the address bar of the user's browser)?

Further, would the pages from exampledomain.com still behave the same?  Would "exampledomain.com/about.php" show the same as "example.subdomain.maindomain.com/about.php"?

The answer to this just may be unGoogleable.... I tried!!

Thanks for the help guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking if you can make example.subdomain.maindomain.com resolve to the same IP address as example.subdomain.maindomain.com, then the answer is yes it is pretty easy.

Since your question seems to be about HTTP though, it becomes a lot more difficult.  How happens on the web server is very specific to the configuration, and possibly the design of any webapps running there.

If you control the main web server and have some level of control of any content/script on the server the answer is probably yes, that you can make it happen.  But we will not be able to help you do this without a more information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which webserver you're using but if it's apache one option is reverse proxying using mod_proxy module. Pretty straightforward to setup for basic functionality.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse